# Triggering Windows Store background task from Band tile opened events

Tags: microsoft-band

Is there a good way to trigger a Windows Store background task when a band tile is opened?  And are there any examples for working with the band from a background task with the latest SDK?  I have seen mentions of the ability to do so but can't find any code examples of this.

I have a scenario where the tile's content is only valid for a short time (~30 seconds) and would like to wake up a background service on the phone while the band's tile is open to update the content as needed.

I was hoping to find an IBackgroundTrigger in the SDK that would do the trick but no luck there.  The best I can think of to fill this need would be to have a task that uses a system trigger and hooks up listeners for the tile opened/closed events.  This seems like a lot of unnecessary work for the task though and could end up with unnecessary battery usage on the phone.

Thanks,
Tony

Comment: This sounds exactly like my issue. I also want to have a background task which "listens" for band events which should be possible with the newest SDK. Did you make any progress yet? Otherwise count me in hunting down possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that is not possible. As far as I can see from the SDK, the app on the phone has to be running to allow a tile on the band to send an event back to the phone.

An alternative would be to open your app from the Band using a voice command. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't give the user experience I'm looking for.  It seems like this is a big limitation of the band...

As a simple example, lets say I want to have audio playback controls on the band.  I can have a background task on the phone that handles grabbing the current media player and invoking the pause/play/back/forward commands.  But how does the app's task listen to the band tile?  Without being able to trigger the task when the tile is opened I would have to find a work around that keeps the task open constantly, stealing performance and battery unnecessarily.